# trying to access EL variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, el

I have a JSP where I have defined a JSTL variable as:

```
<c:set var="productName">
    <fmt:message key="product.name" />
</c:set>
```

Now, I want to access this variable in javascript, I tried the following

```
var prodName = '<c:out value="${productName}"/>'
alert(prodName)
```

but this does not print the value of the variable, instead it just prints:

```
<c:out value="${productName}"/>
```

What am I missing?

Also I was using `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` in my JSP. Now, I am moving the code to Javascript. How do I retrieve the value of `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` in Javascript code? Please note I cannot use onlick or inline javascript in my HTML to pass this value from JSTL to javascript because I am using content security policy that does not allow that. Please suggest something.

Comment: "instead it just prints:"  what does it print?

Comment: I fixed the issue where stackoverflow was earlier truncating the code

Answer (score 0):

A trick that I have used in the past to transfer variables is to put the value of the variable in a data attribute that JavaScript picks up on.  For example:

```
<div class="demo" data-prodname="${ productName }"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert($('.demo').data('prodname'));
</script>
```

However, this can be sensitive if the variable you're trying to output into the attribute has quotes (something like a JSON string).  They would need to be escaped or HTML encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using the `<c:out` expression in the single-quoted strings. All you need is `'${productName}'`

I also recommend setting your page context data in a single JSON-style object literal in a script tag rather than trying to drop it into the HTML or for immediate execution in JS code. That's much more flexible, legible, and easier to work with for a client-side dev. If it's needed by the behavior layer, keep it in an easy, obvious data format in one central location, as isolated from the view and the JavaScript that makes use of the data as much as possible and you will be doing a 5000% more obvious, legible and maintainable job than the what comes out of the templating layers of the vast majority of Java codebases I've been exposed to as a primarily client-side dev.

Comment: you mean '${productName}' in javascript? That does not work for me. It just prints the string ${productName}. The problem is that it's not evaluating the value of the expression for some reason.